# Get the donation value back from Paypal donation button?

Tags: php, paypal

I was wondering if it's possible that paypal give me from the callback function the amount the user have donated through paypal? I need this so I can make the total amount on the website up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes- if you set up an IPN URL on your PayPal account, for EVERY transaction on your account, that URL will receive a callback.

Look here: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNSetup

Here is the sample code: https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623

Comment: Does IPN works for donation too with the 2.3% + 0.30$ rate because it's an non-profit website ?

Comment: The IPN returns the 'mc_gross' and as far as I'm aware, you have to work out the sub-total (i.e. the amount including the PP fee) yourself.